# no known conversion for argument 1 from [mother class] to [child class]

Tags: c++, class, type-conversion

Here's my problem, I try to copy the content of [Mother class] into [Child class] like this:

```
    class Trick
    {
    public:
        Trick();

    protected:
        std::string _name;
        int _point;
    };

    class TrickGraph : public Trick
    {
    public:
        TrickGraph();

    protected:
        sf::Vector2i _pos;
        sf::Vector2u _size;
    };

    class Sheet
    {
    public:
        Sheet()
        {
            _trick = NULL;
        }

        void set_trick(const Trick *trick)
        {
             if (_trick)
                 delete _trick;
            _trick = new TrickGraph();
            *(_trick) = *trick;
        }

    protected:
        TrickGraph *_trick;
    };
```

And after that g++ prints this error at the line `*(_trick) = *trick;`:

```
`In member function ‘void Sheet::set_trick(const Trick*)’:`
`error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘*((Sheet*)this)->Sheet::_trick = * trick’`
`note: candidate is:`
`note: TrickGraph& TrickGraph::operator=(const TrickGraph&)`
`note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const Trick’ to ‘const TrickGraph&’`
`make: *** [...] Error 1`
```

I tried lot of things to resolve it, but as you can see I am posting on stack overflow...
So if you can help me, that would be great :D

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/S8sGsA) if I remove the rogue `:` in the first line. Does the error really come from this code?

Comment: Sorry I miss type that... :S I edit it then

Comment: No, g++ does not produce that error with that code, even if you fix the trivial errors. Post some code that reproduces the error.

Comment: okay, I didn't want to post all the code to go straight to the point but it is may more complicated :S I'm edeting it then

Comment: Before posting code, copy and paste the exact code you are going to post to `ideone.com` and hit Run. Does it give the same errors you are asking about? No? You are wasting everyone's time.

Comment: I am sorry, I just wanted to help to do not pass too long time for me...

Comment: Well, you cannot assign a child to a parent. The language doesn't let you do that because normally that would be a grave error. You have to overload the assignment operator in your child class if you really want to do such a thing (or use casts which is ugly and dangerous and is not recommended).

Comment: Okay, thanks you I didn't know that. I though it would copy all parent content into child. but yeah obviously it cant work that way. Thanks a lot. Post an Answer and I'll approve it ;)

Answer (score -1):

Finally I did it an other way that works. I set a Trick *_trick attribute in TrickGraph and it is not the child of Trick by the way. I had to change some few things aside to make that works but... it works !

Thanks to n.m.